# removing numeric value from a string

Tags: python, perl, bash, shell

I have a file of 2000 rows and 1 column

```
1007_s_at1
1007_s_at2
1007_s_at3
1007_s_at4
1007_s_at5
1007_s_at6
1007_s_at7
1007_s_at8
1007_s_at9
1007_s_at10
```

looks like above, I want to remove the last numeric value after "at". In principle whatever number is in the last should be truncated.

I have tried things like splitting them and then rejoioning it, but it just complicates the problem and I am far away from answer.

Could you please suggest something in bash or shell or python or perl to solve this.

An output like below is desired

```
   1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
    1007_s_at
```

Thank you

Comment: This is a trivial problem for regular expressions. What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i -e 's/[[:digit:]]*$//' filename
```

Comment: Hi! What is the difference with g and without g.sed -i -e 's/[[:digit:]]*$//g' filename     Thank you

Comment: `g` means "global" which means that it will apply the substitution for as many times as the pattern matches.  Because I am using an anchor (`$`) the flag is meaningless and I removed it.

Answer (score 5):

With **Perl**:

```
perl -p -e "s/\d+$//" input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Just pass `string.digits` to `.rstrip()` to remove digits from the right-hand side of your strings:

```
import string
with open('inputfile') as infile, open('outputfile') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line.rstrip().rstrip(string.digits) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the only the number at the end changes you could potentially splice:

```
>>> a = '1007_s_at1'
>>> a[0:9]
'1007_s_at'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Python**

Just strip all digits from the end.

```
>>> "1007_s_at10".rstrip('01234567890')
'1007_s_at'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux or Unix a simple one liner solution would be:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/\d+$//g' file.txt
```

if Windows:

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/\d+$//g" file.txt
```

If you already know what it is doing then well and good otherwise, in very simple terms, `-i` switch with `.bak` would first create a backup of your `file.txt` and name it `file.txt.bak`.

The `-p` option would then loop over the entries in the file and print/save the output in `file.txt` after `s/\d+$//g` removes the digits in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody's suggested a bash solution yet:

```
shopt -s extglob
while read line; do
    echo "${line%%*([0-9])}"
done < filename
```